# Deleting sub-records in Asp.Net web api 2 and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2, put

I am getting frustrated with a problem I cannot solve in Asp.Net web api 2, when I want to deal with update requests which in face contain a set of adding, deleting and editing sub-records (or details) of a master record. To make it clearer, imagine I have the following two model classes:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Description;
    public decimal Total;

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems; 
}
```

And:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id;
    public int OrderId;
    public Notes;
}
```

Now, the deal is that an "update" request of an `Order` record, in fact contains a set of edit, add and delete operations on the `OrderItem` records, because those child records might have been modified in different ways.

For example, an original order may be:

```
Order: { Id:1, Description:"test", Total:10, 
         OrderItems: [
                         { Id:1, OrderId:1, Notes:"nothing!" },
                         { Id:2, OrderId:2, Notes:"nothing at all!" }
                     ]}
```

The updated record sent via a PUT request may be:

```
Order:{Id:1, Description:"test", Total:10, OrderItems:[
  {Id:1, OrderId:1, Notes:"SOMETHING!"},
  {Id:4, OrderId:2, Notes:"just some text..."}
]}
```

In which case, that PUT request needs to cause the following operations on the `OrderItem` database records:

- delete orderItem with Id=2,
- Add an orderItem with Id=4,
- Update the orderItem with Id=1 (to reflect the "Notes" changes")

I am using the following code:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutOrder(int id, Order order)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (id != order.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    foreach (OrderItem oi in order.OrderItems)
    {
        db.Entry(oi).State = oi.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    }

    db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!OrderExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

The foreach loop handles the add and update part perfectly, but I have no working logic to handle the delete part. The scenario is that the orderItem to be deleted does not even exist in the JSON that is being sent through the request.

Comment: you can add one more properties with `OrderItems` as boolean say `IsDeleted` and check `IsDeleted flag` and according to flag delete records.

Answer (score 1):

Added one more property in your OrderItem class to detect whether records are deleted or not.

Let's Say `IsDeleted as bool` and check IsDeleted flag and based on flag delete or add/update OrderItems.

**OrderItem** class :

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id;
    public int OrderId;
    public Notes;
}
```

original order may be:

```
Order: { Id:1, Description:"test", Total:10, 
     OrderItems: [
                     { Id:1, OrderId:1, Notes:"nothing!", IsDeleted : false },
                     { Id:2, OrderId:2, Notes:"nothing at all!", IsDeleted : false }
                 ]}
```

an original order may be:

```
Order:{Id:1, Description:"test", Total:10, OrderItems:[
{Id:1, OrderId:1, Notes:"SOMETHING!",IsDeleted : false},
{ Id:2, OrderId:2, Notes:"nothing at all!", IsDeleted : true }
{Id:4, OrderId:2, Notes:"just some text...",IsDeleted : false}
]}
```

In foreach:

```
foreach (OrderItem oi in order.OrderItems)
{
    if(io.IsDeleted){
        d.Entry(oi).state = EntityState.Deleted;
    }else{
        db.Entry(oi).State = oi.Id == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
    }
}

db.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;

try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    if (!OrderExists(id))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: To be honest I actually thought of this before posting my question, but then I thought I am looking for a solution that preferably wouldn't require changes on my core models. Thanks for your insight though :)